# How to run on browser start

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm new to Firefox addon development.
I have the following code:

```
var windows = require("sdk/windows").browserWindows;
windows.on("open", function() {
    // do stuff
});
```

But this only runs for windows created **after** the browser is started, not the first one.
How can I fix this?

I know I could just copy the code outside of the open event, but then it also runs when the addon is installed and I don't want that.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tutorials/Listening_for_load_and_unload#options.loadReason).

```
exports.main = function (options, callbacks) {
    if (options.loadReason == "startup") {
        // do stuff     
    }
};
```