# Firefox Webextensions: Run code on browser start

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon-webextensions

Using the WebExtensions api, how do I run some code on browser start? I need to be able to distinguish browser restart events from normal start events.

Before WebExtensions, it could be done by checking the loadReason as mentioned in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35555039/how-to-run-on-browser-start). Reference: [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tutorials/Listening_for_load_and_unload#options.loadReason).

One way would be to listen for the windows.onCreated event and then check if it is the first window created ([MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/windows)). However, I don't see a way to distinguish browser restart events using this method.

EDIT:

My use case: I need to open a few tabs when the browser is opened. But, I do not want the tabs opened when I'm just restarting the browser for whatever reason (ex: installing updates).

EDIT 1:

Checking if there are tabs with the same url already open will not always work correctly because some urls redirect to another page (a login page for example), which will result in the urls not matching and the tab being opened again.

Comment: You could check whether the tabs you want to open are already open using the browser.tabs API?

Comment: The problem with checking whether the tabs are already open is that some of the urls will redirect to another page (a login page for example), which will result in the urls not matching and the tab being opened again.

Comment: And you don't know the URLs you are redirecting to?

Comment: No. The urls that will open on browser start are configurable, not a fixed set of urls. So the addon cannot know every possible redirect url.

For example, if a user configures it to open a bitbucket repository url, the url will redirect to the bitbucket login page first, and the actual repository page will open after the user logs in.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by "normal start events", extension startup outside of browser startup would only happen for relatively uncommon events like the first install, manual disbaling/enabling, or extension updates.

But in any case, the runtime.onStartup event is what you want:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/runtime/onStartup

Comment: Thanks for your answer. By normal startup events, I meant a user starting the browser, as opposed to the user restarting the browser to install updates or for any other reason. I've edited the question to make this clearer.
Do you know any way to distinguish a browser restart with the runtime.onStartup event?

Comment: I see, it sounds like you really care about whether a previous session has been restored or not.  Note that a previous session can be restored even in a "normal startup".  I don't have any ideas for how to detect session restart though.

Comment: Yes, it seems like there's no direct way to detect whether the previous session is being restored. I'll try Smile4Ever's answer - hopefully, it should work.
Maybe I should ask around in the mozilla forum, to see if there are any plans to enhance an existing api or create a new api to support this.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is probably keeping track of the urls and tabIds of tabs you opened in background.js. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/onCreated

```
let tabUrls = [];
function handleCreated(tab) {
  tabUrls[tab.id] = tab.url;
}

browser.tabs.onCreated.addListener(handleCreated);
```

Then you'd have to subscribe to the onUpdated event to track previous URL of the tabs you opened. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/onUpdated

```
function handleUpdated(tabId, changeInfo, tabInfo) {
  if (changeInfo.url && tabUrls[tabId] != null) {
    tabUrls[tabId] = changeInfo.url;
  }
}

browser.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(handleUpdated);
```

Then you'd have to subscribe to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/onRemoved to delete urls of tabs you opened that have been closed.

```
function handleRemoved(tabId, removeInfo) {
  tabUrls[tabId] = null;
}

browser.tabs.onRemoved.addListener(handleRemoved);
```

To persist these changes across browser (re)starts, you will need to save tabUrls variable inside browser.storage.local when a tab is created, updated or removed (without tabIds):

```
function updateStorage(){
  browser.storage.local.set("urlValues", Object.values(tabUrls)); // Store URLs without tab ids. They will probably not be the same after a restart or quit, you can only assume the urls are correct
}
```

Next steps:

- Read from local storage on initialisation of background.js (just call a function in background.js, you can call that function init or something like that), check if any of the current URLs match to those stored URLs or the start URLs. If no match is found, you should open that URL.
- Remove onUpdated listener after a second or less, when all required tabs are opened, to prevent user navigation from impacting your logic

You could use webRequest https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/webRequest to see whether the page you are requesting is a redirect (statusCode = 302 or 301 - see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/webRequest/onHeadersReceived)